# Visual Basic Script to register an DLL as part of an MSI

Tags: visual-studio, dll, vbscript, registry, windows-installer

I have an MSI created with Visual Studio, and I want to register an DLL, craxdtr.dll. So I created an Visual Basic Script to do it, and add it as an custom action at install.

The problem is when the installer should run the script it says:

*There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A script required for this install to complete could not be found. Contact your support personnel or package vendor.*

The script looks like this:

```
Dim WshShell
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Dim szInstallDir = Session.Property("TARGETDIR")
Dim szDllPath = szInstallDir & "\\craxdrt.dll"
WshShell.run "regsvr32 /s " & szDllPath
Set WshShell = nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to do any of this.  If you go to the file properties and set the Register property to vsdraCOM, MSI should handle all of this for you automatically.

Comment: I have tried that option, and vsdraComSelfReg to, but at install it throws an error that sounds something like this :  craxdtr.dll could not be register, and i have three option continue, try again and exit.

Comment: Well, I'd create a merge module using WiX and use Heat to harvest the COM metadata for the DLL.  That said, if you want to go down the VBSCript route, realize the WScript object won't exist because you are running in ActiveScript hosted by MSI not WSCript or CScript.  Also realize that you are running deferred so you won't be able to access the TARGETDIR property.  You'll have to extract your information from the CustomActionData property.  That and Script CA's are notoriously brittle.